# Turn on/off camera flashlight on Android

Tags: java, android, camera, xamarin, flashlight

Is it possible to switch between on and off multiple times in a short time the camera flashlight of an Android device? If so, how?

I am trying to create an app that is able to send data over the flashlight blinks.

Comment: yes it is possible... please send your current code and i will guide you how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it in code, use this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/04/android-developing-flashlight-application/).

Basically you use the camera flash in the following manner:

```
private Camera camera;
Parameters params;

private void turnOnFlash() {
        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
    } 
}
```